# Is “I’m going to go to vote” correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Can I say the following sentence in English?

> I’m going to go to vote.

“Vote” is a verb here.

Comment: I'm going to go for voting.

Comment: @VijayaRagavan: not really; that doesn't sound natural.

Comment: It makes sense, but the "to go" seems unnecessary.

Comment: I agree with Steve.

Comment: It would be nice if you added some clarification about **why** you asked this question. Of course you can say "I'm going to go to vote." You can also say, "The Klingons are farthing to wax." Whether it's grammatical, or interpretable, or is the best way to say what you're wanting to say – that's another matter. I suspect you're wondering if your your sentence violates some grammatical rule, but it would be helpful if you elaborated more on that.

Comment: Well,a friend of mine said this.We aren´t native speakers,it sounded strange to me but I couldn´t find anything wrong.Now I see it´s correct.Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can.

> I'm going<sup>1</sup> to go<sup>2</sup> to vote.

The two *go*s indicate different things:

1. *Going to* indicates future time, like *will*.
2. *Go* is a verb of movement; you will go somewhere to vote.

So this sentence would be most appropriate if you're about to head out the door to go to your local voting site, and you want to tell someone the reason you're leaving.

Most verbs can be put together like the above (A to B to C to D).  However, the verb of motion *go* is a special verb, and it can appear with another verb without *to* in-between:

> I'm going<sup>1</sup> to go<sup>2</sup> vote.

This means the same thing as the above.  This shorter sentence is more natural-sounding, particularly for American speakers; usually we leave out the *to* when we use *go* like this.  (Some British English speakers regard this construction as an Americanism, and a few (particularly older) speakers don't accept it.)

> I'm going<sup>1</sup> to vote.

The simpler sentence "I'm going to vote" is different.  It only has the future *going to*, not the verb of movement *go*.  So it means "I will vote" (at some point in the future) and doesn't tell us that you're about to go somewhere to vote.  This simpler sentence would be appropriate if you've decided in advance that you will vote.  It can be said weeks or months in advance.

Comment: You might want to mention that the most natural-sounding version omits the second *to*: "I'm going to go vote."

Comment: The second example *I'm going to go vote.* is distinctive as American English. In the UK, the first and third examples would be much more likely.

Comment: Martha, @Tristan, thank you both--I've updated my answer in response to both comments.  (Tristan, I specifically wrote "some British English speakers, especially older speakers" based on the linguist Arnold Zwicky's characterization in [this blog post](http://arnoldzwicky.org/2012/08/28/qsv/) about the "quasi-serial verb construction", which is what the second example uses.)

Comment: snail, I don't intend to give the impression that I do not accept that wording. I just mean that in the UK, I have not heard anyone use the word *go*, like it was used in the second example. They normally say things like *go to* or *go and*. I have only heard Americans use it like in your example.

Comment: The last sentence can be parsed two ways:  "I'm (going to) vote" - as in I will vote sometime in the future,  OR  "I'm going (to vote)" - as in, I'm leaving now to participate in the election.  Context is the only way to disambiguate them.